# How capture the info into a HTML checkbox?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have created an HTML form which asks the user what types of marketing they are using. Depending on their answers, I intend to build a PHP recommender system based on those variations. I have started with a base function but it keeps returning the same echo statement regardless if I select none of the checkboxes or all of them. Here is the HTML code.

```
 <p>Marketing Mix:</p>    
 <input type="checkbox" name="TV" value="TV">TV<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Radio" value="Radio">Radio<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Search" value="Search">Search<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Mobile" value="Mobile">Mobile<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Mail" value="Mail">Direct Mail<br>
 <br>
```

And here is the PHP function to process the HTML form.

```
 function adMix () {
 $tv = (isset($_POST['TV']));
 $radio = (isset($_POST['Radio']));
 $search = (isset($_POST['Search']));
 $mobile = (isset($_POST['Mobile']));
 $mail = (isset($_POST['Mail']));
 if ($tv || $radio || $search || $mobile || $mail) {
     echo "You are running a comprehensive ad campaign.";
 } else {
     echo "You can do more to market your dealership.";
    }
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried coding this six ways to Sunday but it's been a while since I wrote in PHP and just can't figure it out.

Comment: did you mean AND (&&) **not** OR (||)?

Comment: You have form `method="post"`?

Comment: Which echo are you getting?

Comment: @Steve:  I bet on the second one.

Comment: check @AbraCadaver comment, your code is ok unless you have forgotten to add `method="post"` to your form tag. without that, the default method is $_GET

Comment: Could be a caching problem

Comment: It's hard to say and we need more information in order to give you a definite answer. Now, do you want to make sure that a user chooses at least ONE of the checkboxes, or all, or a minimum of choices? That will determine everything.

Comment: Yes it is method="post" and I did mean && not ||

Comment: The point is to have a number of boxes selected, if they have them all selected, it's comprehensive, if they only have, lets say two... then it will echo "You can do more to market your dealership." Currently, it just keeps echoing "You are running a comprehensive ad campaign" regardless of the checkbox selection.

Comment: I've posted something below that you can easily modify, which I've changed how it's done; and much simpler.

Comment: @MatthieuMcClintock see the answers, don't forget check one as correct ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a method where you don't need to worry about giving your checkboxes different names, just checking if there were a certain amount of those checkboxes chosen.

Each chosen option's value will automatically get echo'd as they're populated through a `foreach`.

***Sidenote:*** To choose how many you wish to have as a minimum, change the number 3 to the number you want.

This uses PHP's [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function to "count" how many were chosen and using the same name for all checkboxes as an array.

You can change: (*if it equals to 3 or more*)

```
if(count($_POST['choices']) >= 3)
```

to: (*if it equals exactly 3*)

```
if(count($_POST['choices']) == 3)
```

in order to get an exact match, or leaving it as:

```
if(count($_POST['choices']) >= 3)
```

to check if 3 or more have been chosen. You can change that number as you see fit.

```
<form action="" method="post">
 <p>Marketing Mix:</p>    
 <input type="checkbox" name="choices[]" value="TV">TV<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="choices[]" value="Radio">Radio<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="choices[]" value="Search">Search<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="choices[]" value="Mobile">Mobile<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="choices[]" value="Mail">Direct Mail<br>
 <br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php 

 function adMix () {

    if(isset($_POST['submit']) 
    && isset($_POST['choices']) ){

    echo "You entered ";

    foreach($_POST['choices'] as $choice){

        echo "<b>" . $choice . "</b> ";

}

if(count($_POST['choices']) >= 3){

     echo "You are running a comprehensive ad campaign.";
 } 

else{
     echo "<i>You can do more to market your dealership.</i>";
    }
 }

}

 adMix();

?>
```

Comment: The thing is if they're not doing radio, or TV let's say, I may need to recommend they do that kind of advertising.

Comment: @MatthieuMcClintock That would require another and/or different conditional statement.

Comment: Yes but isn't there a way to code it so I can adjust it later to account for different variations of selected checkboxes?

Comment: @MatthieuMcClintock I'll see what I can do. It's a matter of checking if any are set using `isset()` then assigning variables for each.

Comment: As far as 'choices' go. How would I write an if statement like if tv and radio are selected, then recommend this?

Comment: @MatthieuMcClintock `if(isset($_POST['var'])){ $var=$_POST['var']; } echo $var;` etc. which is basically what you were doing.

Comment: I'm sorry could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You need a form and a button to send your info, try this:

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
 <p>Marketing Mix:</p>    
 <input type="checkbox" name="TV" value="TV">TV<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Radio" value="Radio">Radio<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Search" value="Search">Search<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Mobile" value="Mobile">Mobile<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Mail" value="Mail">Direct Mail<br>
 <br>

<input type=submit value='Send' name = 'send'>
</form>

<?php
 function adMix () {
 $tv = isset($_POST['TV']);
 $radio = isset($_POST['Radio']);
 $search = isset($_POST['Search']);
 $mobile = isset($_POST['Mobile']);
 $mail = isset($_POST['Mail']);
 if (($tv || $radio || $search || $mobile || $mail)) {
     echo "You are running a comprehensive ad campaign.";
 } else if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
     echo "You can do more to market your dealership.";
    }
 }

 adMix();

 ?>
```

Comment: I already have those that's not the issue I just didn't include them.